# Kotlin: my logs showing java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.playlist.model.PlaylistResponse cannot be cast to java.util.List error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

my model response is an object that contains another object and list in it. Example:

```
{
    "name": " ",
    "tracks": {
        "title": " "
        "artists": {
            "name": " "
        }
        "images": {
            "poster": {
            "url": " "
        }
      }
    }
}
```

therefore this is my model data class:
package com.example.playlist.model

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class PlaylistResponse(
    @SerializedName("name")
    val name: String,
    @SerializedName("tracks")
    val tracks: List<Track>,
)
```

i used adapter to bind my class with my data:
package com.example.playlist.Adapter

```
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.playlist.R
import com.example.playlist.model.PlaylistResponse
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.playlist_item.view.*


class PlaylistAdapter(private val context: Context, private val playList: List<PlaylistResponse>):
    RecyclerView.Adapter<PlaylistAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var trackImage : ImageView
        var trackName : TextView
        var artistName : TextView

        init{
            trackImage = itemView.image_track
            trackName = itemView.name_track
            artistName = itemView.name_artist
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        var itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.playlist_item, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        Picasso.get().load(playList[position].tracks[position].images.poster.url).into(holder.trackImage)
        holder.trackName.text = playList[position].tracks[position].title
        holder.artistName.text = playList[position].tracks[position].artists[position].name

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return playList.size
    }
}
```

and i used the adapter in my playListActivity class:

```
package com.example.playlist

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.playlist.Adapter.PlaylistAdapter
import com.example.playlist.model.PlaylistResponse
import com.example.playlist.network.ApiClient
import com.example.playlist.network.PrefService
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_playlist.*
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response


class PlaylistActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var prefService: PrefService
    private lateinit var apiClient: ApiClient
    lateinit var layoutManager: LinearLayoutManager
    lateinit var adapter : PlaylistAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_playlist)

        apiClient = ApiClient()
        prefService = PrefService(this)

        recyclerPlaylist.setHasFixedSize(true)
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerPlaylist.layoutManager = layoutManager

        fetchPlaylist()

    }

    private fun fetchPlaylist() {

        apiClient.getApiService(this).fetchPlaylist(token = "Bearer ${prefService.fetchAuthToken()}")
            .enqueue(object : Callback<PlaylistResponse> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<PlaylistResponse>, t: Throwable) {

                }

                override fun onResponse(call: Call<PlaylistResponse>, response: Response<PlaylistResponse>) {
                    adapter = PlaylistAdapter(baseContext, response.body() as List<PlaylistResponse>)
                    recyclerPlaylist.adapter = adapter
                }
            })
    }
}
```

i knew the error is caused by this line :

```
adapter = PlaylistAdapter(baseContext, response.body() as List<PlaylistResponse>)
```

but i didn't know how to turn the object into a list. i have watch & read countless of videos and articles but still failed to understand how to solved my problem. i'm very new to kotlin therefore any solutions and helps are highly appreciated.

Comment: Your model response is not list so that you can't turn it into list

Comment: i understand. what should i change in order to turn it into list? because i want to display a list of playlist cardview

Comment: That's weird because your list count is always 1.

Comment: does it mean that i cannot display list?

Comment: You can get it as a object and put it into list.

Comment: i'm sorry @GHH but how should i do that? i just learnt kotlin and i didn't sure how to get it as a object and display it in a list

Answer (score 0):

```
data class LoginResponse(
var status: Boolean = false,
var data: LoginData? = null,
var message: String = ""
)

data class LoginData(
var id: Int? = null,
var uuid: String = "",
var name: String = "",
var email: String = "",
var email_verified_at: String = "",
var api_token: String = "",
var created_at: String = "",
var updated_at: String = ""
)
```

Create Class Like This

Comment: i've created my data and response class (like the one above) by referring the postman. but still produce the same error. May i know the reason why i have to set all my data to null? thank you in advance